# Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`UserTable`)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn React Hooks in functional components, and am following along with [React Hooks tutorial](https://www.taniarascia.com/crud-app-in-react-with-hooks/) but am getting the error: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`UserTable`), and the error stack indicates this is related to the **onClick={props.deleteUser(user.id)}** property in the **delete button** in `UserTable.js`. I saw several posts indicating that one should try **useEffect()** to get around this issue, so I tried having **deleteUser** update a state variable, and then have useEffects change the **users** array. While the code compiled fine, the page simply hung and eventually timed out with an "out of memory" error (I assume caused by an endless cycle of trying to render and re-render?). Any ideas how to fix this situation?

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import UserTable from './tables/UserTable';
import AddUserForm from './forms/AddUserForm';

const App= () =>  {

  const usersData = [
    {id: 1, name: "Tania", username: "floppydiskette"},
    {id: 2, name: "Craig", username: "siliconeidolon" },
    {id: 3, name: "Ben", username: "benisphere"}
  ]

   const [users, setUsers] = useState(usersData);

    const addUser = (user) => {
      user.id = users.length+1;
      setUsers([...users,user])
     }

   const deleteUser = (id) => {
     setUsers(users.filter((user)=>user.id !== id))
   }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1> SIMPLE CRUD APP WITH HOOKS</h1>
      <div className="flex-row">
         <div className = "flex-large">
           <h2> Add User </h2>
            <AddUserForm addUser={addUser}/>
         </div>
        <div className = "flex-large">
              <h2>View Users</h2>
              <UserTable users={users} deleteUser={deleteUser}/> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

UserTable.js

```
import React from 'react';

const UserTable = (props) => {

    return(
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {props.users.length > 0 ? (
                props.users.map((user) => (
                <tr key={user.id}>
                    <td>{user.name}</td>
                    <td>{user.username}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button className="button muted-button">Edit</button>
>>> This triggers the `cannot update a component . . .` error:
                        <button className="button muted-button" onClick={props.deleteUser(user.id)}>Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ))
            ) : (
                <tr colspan={3}>No Users</tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    );
}

export default UserTable
```

Comment: You are immediately invoking the `deleteUser` function in the child. `onClick={props.deleteUser(user.id)}` should probably be `onClick={() => props.deleteUser(user.id)}`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: Thank you! That did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to change

```
onClick={props.deleteUser(user.id)}>Delete</button>
```

to

```
onClick={()=> props.deleteUser(user.id)}>Delete</button>
```

Otherwise your delete function will get automaticaly fired on render itself